# Is Crystal Reports a viable option in this scenario?

Tags: linux, oracle, reporting-services, crystal-reports

We are using an application that uses Oracle database and an embedded license shipped with the application.

We have a problem in that the reporting possibilities that are shipped with the application are extremely basic and outdated.

The application is not dated at all, and is the definite leader in the industry that we're in, it's just the reporting side never seems to receive much attention, or other customers don't have the same reporting expectations as we do.

To give some idea, the reporting side allows

- Database fields
- Text fields

and that is all. All our tables are made out of the `|`, `_` characters etc.

We are looking to get rid of all our reports in the application and switch to a third party system for the reporting side, looking at Crystal Reports.

Would we just need Crystal Reports installed on the IT department computers that design reports, or would it be needed on all computers in our organisation that needs to print, view reports etc.?

Is it possible to schedule batch reports, for e.g. for all orders being delivered today, generate an Invoice report for each order and e-mail it to the customer where all Invoice information including the customers e-mail address being pulled from our database?

Are there any other routes to look at\other software packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crystal is an option , but will be just part of the solution because it will allow you to develop the reports. The other part is to provide the users with an interface to run the reports. You will need Crystal designer installed on at least one computer in IT – it will be used to develop the reports. You will need also to find a system , which will allow you to run the reports on the users computers. This other system should allow you not just to run the reports, but to control who is able to run them. For example you don't want anybody in the company to be able to run a report , which is showing current sales and profit or a list of all employees with their addresses and SSN. My advice is to start looking first for the system , which is going to run the reports and then to decide , which reporting tool to use. For example , if you have a license for SQLServer you have a license for SSRS (SQLServer Reporting Services). This is a server based system , which will allow to handle the report distribution. There is also a report development tool for SSRS , which is free. So check this option. As I said Crystal is an option too. There is Crystal Server , which can be used to distribute the reports and also a bunch of 3rd party systems, which might be a cheaper alternative. In general Web based system like SSRS and Crystal Server will be cheaper to maintain, but Desktop systems are usually faster and provide richer user interface. There are plenty of options for Crystal reports. I was using 2 : Jeff-net web portal (http://www.jeff-net.com/jnrrbw.htm) and R-Tag report manager (http://www.r-tag.com). Jeff-net is a web portal, which means you can use from any computer in the company , without additional installation. R-Tag is a desktop system and requires installation on each computer , where it will be used , but it supports multiple report types including Crystal reports and dashboards. There are also other tools for Crystal reports. You can check these links:
Desktop report viewers http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/crystal-reports-viewers
Desktop report schedulers http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/desktop-scheduling-engines
Web report schedulers http://kenhamady.com/cru/comparisons/server-based-scheduling-engines

If you a looking for a Linux based solution you will be restricted to a web portal.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. So the idea is that you use Crystal Reports to design the report and that is all, and use some third-party software to do everything else related to the report?

Comment: Yes. 3rd party software is considered any software not produced by SAP, the producer of Crystal reports. You can use Crystal server, which is not 3rd party, but you need to consider the price. Crystal designer is not a good option because anybody will be able to change the report, you will be not able to control the permissions  and there will be a lot of manual operations because you cannot automate tasks.

Comment: SAP has also a Crystal reports viewer (free) , which is just as a viewer , but it cannot refresh report data. You need to run the report and save it with the data and then all the users will be able to open it using Crystal viewer. This will work as Adobe reader. If somebody generates the PDF you can use the reader to open it , but you cannot generate or change PDF with it. If your users will need to open static reports, without changing parameters you might consider this option too.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. The SAP website seems to over complicate things, I just needed a simple explanation as you've provided!

Comment: If I needed to do something like 'For all orders being delivered today, create an Invoice report for each order, and send them to the customer (where their e-mail address is pulled from the database), a single e-mail with multiple attachments per customer'. Is that sort of thing possible would you know?

Comment: Yes this is possible and there are 2 ways to do this. Most of the reporting engines will allow you to create data driven reports: first you will define a query ( the one , which will retrieve all the orders for the day) then you will choose one or more reports to run against each row returned by this query. You can use the values returned by the query as parameters inside the report(s). You can use these values also to create a file name, mail merger email body, subject or to send email to an email address returned by the query.

Comment: Data driven reports are available in SQLServer Reporting services but unfortunately this feature requires Enterprise edition. The other approach is report bursting, which is provided by Crystal reports. You need to create a report with at least one group , then during the bursting the file will be separated to 1 file per group and will be further processed. In your scenario you will need to create a report , which returns all orders for the day, group by OrderID and place the invoice inside the group. When you run the report it will generate one huge file with many invoices.

Comment: During the bursting this file will be separated in pieces and a file will be generated for each invoice. This file could be send by e-mail to an email defined inside the report. Crystal server supports burtsing. As fara as I know SSRS - does not. There are 3rd party tools that support one or both methods. R-Tag can do both and I am using it for a similar scenario. There is another tool Visaul Cut , which can do just bursting. I never used it, but you can research it.

Comment: Can R-Tag be used without Crystal Reports? I'm reading their website and see it mentions direct SQL queries but not sure if that's what it means.

Comment: Best will be if you contact their support. The tool can be used without Crystal, for example you can create your own dashboards, which is totally different report type and is probably the direct SQL query you mentioned. However, since one of the tags in your question is Linux, check first if they have a version that can work on Linux. The version I am using is for Windows Desktop.